# Photosets not opening on tumblr lightbox on the custom tumblr theme I'm using?

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr, tumblr-themes

My friend has set a custom theme to their tumblr, and only after customising everything, they've noticed that, for some reason, the photosets are not being properly displayed on tumblr's lightbox feature. Instead, after being clicked, the image is opened on the page itself, in a weird manner.

My friend wouldn't feel comfortable with me sharing their personal blog here, but I've copied the exact same code they're using to a sideblog so you can see the glitch I'm talking about: https://frescoboy.tumblr.com/

That is the current code of their photosets:

```
    {block:Photoset}
    {Photoset}
    {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Photoset}
```

I'm sorry, I'm pretty much a beginner when it comes to coding, so I'm having a hard time trying to come up with ways of fixing it :( any help or tip will be greatly appreciated!